# unit testing using jasmine marbles

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

I am trying to do a simple test using `jasmine-marbles` but getting errors

This is my test code:

```
describe('MarbleTestingComponent', () => {
  it('should test marble syntax', () => {
    const provided = search('e');
    const expected = cold('(e|)', {e: 'e'});
    console.log(expected, provided);
    expect(provided).toBeObservable(expected);
  })   

});
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Error: 
            Expected: (e|),
            Received: (?|),
            
            Expected:
            [{"frame":0,"notification":{"kind":"N","value":"e","hasValue":true}},{"frame":0,"notification":{"kind":"C","hasValue":false}}]
            
            Received:
            [{"frame":0,"notification":{"kind":"N","value":"e"}},{"frame":0,"notification":{"kind":"C"}}],
```

if I use the `jest` framework, the above code works, but I want to get it working withe default test framework that comes with Angular setup

Any help to sort this error is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try checking the jasmine-marbles version.

I experienced the same issue with using "jasmine-marbles": "^0.9.0" with  "rxjs": "^6.6.7".

Downgrading to "jasmine-marbles": "^0.8.0" resolved the issue.

See supported versions here: https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles#readme

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if can help you but I had the same issue testing effects and I fixed it using https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#with-testscheduler. I think the last versions of jasmine-marbles are not aligned with rxjs.

I hope could be helpful for you.

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem to align with the latest version of RxJS. See the below answer. After downgrading `jasmine-marbles` version I got my issue resolved

Comment: Good to know, in fact, if you see the yarn.lock of the package, you can see that is using `jasmine-marbles@~0.6.0: version "0.6.0"`.